# Compute the line integral by parametrization.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, line-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^i |z|^2dz$$

The hint says to parametrize  the line segment by $z=-1+(1+i)t$, $0 \le t \le 1$. Below is my attempt.

$$dz=0+(1+i)dt$$

$$dz=(1+i)dt$$

Solving for $|z|^2$:

$$|z|^2=(\sqrt{(-1)^2+(1+i)^2})^2$$
$$=1+1+2i-1$$
$$=1+2i$$

Plugging into new integral:

$$\int_0^1 (1+2i)(1+i)dt$$
$$=\int_0^1 (-1+3i)dt$$

$$=-t+3it |_{0}^1$$
$$=-1+3i$$

However, the answer given is $2(1+i)/3$...where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: When you solved for $\abs{z}^2$, you dropped $t$ by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute square should not be a complex number.

$$z = -1 + (1+i)t$$
$$z = -1 + t + it$$
$$z = (-1 + t) + it$$

So:

$$|z| = \sqrt{t^2 + (t-1)^2}$$
$$|z|^2 = t^2 + (t-1)^2 $$